# Add $ symbol and round off values

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have calculated fields and I need to round off those column values.

```
[YearlyProfit_2014] [Yearly Profit], [YearlyProfit_2014] = [MonthlyProfit]/4, [MonthlyProfit] = [WeeklySum]* .50], isnull(sum([YearlyProfit_2014]),0) [YearlyProfit]
```

Now these calculated column has decimal values and I need to round off the values.

Comment: Formatting & rounding should be done at the presentation layer (app UI, report, web interface, etc.), not in the database.

Answer (score 2):

```
select [MonthlyProfit] = '$' + cast(round([WeeklySum]* .50, 18, 2) as varchar(19))
```